# QWebEngineView crashes when accessing specific websites

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

I have a very weird bug with QWebEngineView. Below is some code which creates a QWebEngineView.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QFileInfo, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings, QWebEngineProfile, QWebEnginePage

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        webview = QWebEngineView(self)
        webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        profile = QWebEngineProfile("my_profile", webview)
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, webview)
        webview.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))
        #self.webview.setPage(self.webpage)
        webview.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480)
        webview.show()

        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    app.exec_()
```

My issue is that when I run the code as it is (with the `self.webview.setPage(self.webpage)` line commented out) I am able to open PDF files, however opening YouTube crashes the program. However if I uncomment the line and run it, I can't open PDF files (although it doesn't crash the program it just doesn't open the PDF file), but I can then open YouTube with no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the QWebEngineProfile and QWebEnginePage first and then enable the plugins:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import (
    QWebEnginePage,
    QWebEngineProfile,
    QWebEngineSettings,
    QWebEngineView,
)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        profile = QWebEngineProfile("my_profile", self)
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, self)
        webview = QWebEngineView(self)
        webview.setPage(webpage)
        webview.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        webview.load(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(webview)
        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```